# How to stop scrolling when there is no content to display in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am making angular 6 application where i am making a scrollable divs which has,

**HTML:**

```
<button class="lefty paddle" id="left-button"> PREVIOUS </button>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner" style="background:red"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:green"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:blue"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:yellow"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:orange"></div>
  </div>
<button class="righty paddle" id="right-button"> NEXT </button>
```

**TS:**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const lefty = document.querySelector(".lefty");
let translate = 0;

lefty.addEventListener("click", function() {
    translate += 200;
    container.style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "px" + ")";
});

const righty = document.querySelector(".righty");
righty.addEventListener("click", function() {
    translate -= 200;
    container.style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "px" + ")";
});
  }
```

**Working Stckblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mncf26

In this working demo you can see there is next and previous button which will make translate of `200px` either to right or left as per the click..

Here if the click was made either in left or right even if there is no content it is scrolling `200px` either side..

How can i stop the scroll if there is no content to display??

Comment: Before you transform, check the new translate value. If it's lower then zero. return zero. If it's greater then the container.offsetWidth return the container.offsetWidth.

Comment: use a var to track displacement , demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptxrq7

Comment: @ABOS, ```Yikes! The page you requested couldn't be found.```..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky because you are moving the container in a reverse direction, so you have to play on the negative values of your variables.

I made a [quick stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tb22nt?file=src/app/app.component.html) showing that (and I changed your code a bit to simplify it, sorry), tell me if it is what you want :

```html
<button class="lefty paddle" 
  (click)="translateValue = translateValue + 200" 
  [disabled]="-translateValue <= 0"> PREVIOUS </button>

  <div class="container" #container [ngStyle]="getStyle">
    <div class="inner" *ngFor="let item of elements" [style.background]="item" #items></div>
  </div>

<button class="righty paddle" 
  (click)="translateValue = translateValue - 200"
  [disabled]="-translateValue >= container.offsetWidth"> NEXT </button>
```

Comment: Don't know about the downvoter.. Even my code was edited it solves my issue temporarily.. Thanks for your time and help.. Made upvote for you..